# New DateTime object giving null reference exception in WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, datetime

I am a newbie to `WCF` so please bear with me.

Why would I be getting a `NullReferenceException occured` when trying to create a new `DateTime` object in my `WCF` service.

This is the line of code:

```
DateTime fromDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Ticks);
```

I have tried various approaches like:

```
DateTime fromDate = new DateTime();
DateTime fromDate = DateTime.Now;
```

All 3 lines of code give me a `NullReferenceException occured` error.

Screenshot:

[image]

Am I allowed to use `DateTime` object in `WCF`?

**EDIT:**

Code up to that line:

```
public class CampaignSchedulePlacementService : ICampaignSchedulePlacementService
    {

        public PlacementAdvertRoutingAddressPairsResponce GetPlacementAdvertRoutingAddressPairs(string userName, string password, string routingAddressCode, int monthsBack, int monthsAhead)
        {
            return GetPlacementAdvertRoutingAddressPairsByFilters(userName, password, routingAddressCode, monthsBack, monthsAhead);
        }

        #region Methods

        private PlacementAdvertRoutingAddressPairsResponce GetPlacementAdvertRoutingAddressPairsByFilters(string userName, string password, string routingAddressCode, int monthsBack, int monthsAhead)
        {
            PlacementAdvertRoutingAddressPairsResponce placementAdvertRoutingAddressPairsResponce = new PlacementAdvertRoutingAddressPairsResponce();
            StagingEntityModel stagingEntityModel = null;

            try
            {
                try
                {
                    string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test"].ConnectionString;
                    stagingEntityModel = new StagingEntityModel(RMS.Common.Core.Public.GetEntityConnectionString(connectionString, "Data.EntityFramework.Model.StagingEntityModel"));
                    stagingEntityModel.Connection.Open();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    placementAdvertRoutingAddressPairsResponce.Message = "Failed opening the connection :" + String.Format("{0}\r\n with an inner exception of {1}\r\nand a stack trace of {2}", ex.Message,
                                                                                ex.InnerException != null ? ex.InnerException.Message : "",
                                                                                ex.StackTrace);

                    return placementAdvertRoutingAddressPairsResponce;
                }

                User currentUser = stagingEntityModel.User.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == userName && x.Password == password);

                if (currentUser != null)
                {
                    DateTime fromDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Ticks); //.AddMonths(monthsBack * -1);
                    DateTime toDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Ticks); //.AddMonths(monthsAhead);
```

**EDIT:**

Call stack:

[image]

Comment: What's the line of code **above** that line?

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code above it? You can hover over it to see which object is null

Comment: You are allowed. I'm sure the problem in another place )

Comment: Could you paste the Stack Trace?

Comment: tell me how DateTime fromDate = new DateTime(); can throw NullReference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am i allowed to use DateTime object in WCF?

Most certainly.

Though I can't see the Stack Trace, the line `DateTime fromDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Ticks);` can't really be failing. There's nothing to be `null`. However, this line:

```
stagingEntityModel.User.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == userName && x.Password == password);
```

Could most certainly fail. I think you'll find that `.User` is `null`. And I think you'll also find that Visual Studio, as it seems to do a lot, jumps ahead to some other statement that's not the one that's failing.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it is not null, because it passed that line. Have a look at the code and you will see it goes inside the if and fails on the specific line...

Comment: @Willem, I hear what you're saying my friend, but I think you also hear what I'm saying ... how about you post the Stack Trace as requested and we'll be able to help better.

Comment: @Willem, not the `Call Stack`, the `Stack Trace` that comes with the error. And please don't post the `Stack Trace` as an image, copy the `Stack Trace`, paste it in, and indent it as a code block.

Comment: @Willem How is this connected to what Michael asked?

Comment: @Willem, the `Stack Trace` is in fact the `Stack Trace` and not the `Call Stack` and it doesn't matter what version of Visual Studio you're using. You see that link that says ***View Detail*** on the first-chance exception popup? That's going to have a property in there called ... wait for it ... `Stack Trace`. Now, before you get too high on yourself, remember, we are trying to help ***you*** solve ***your*** problem that ***you*** can't currently solve.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud My apologies. I will add the stack trace. Tired from no sleep. Did not mean to offend you...